# Zebra strips with possible gaps

Tags: lcd, display

My Breville oven display shows some missing characters and some dimmed characters, after 2 crosstown moves. I have  disassembled other devices in the past, but those were repairs for other people.
I can still use the oven now. I am worried that on this display I might make it worse, then I can't use it at all.
On the other hand, I could do a regular routine fix.
Can I clean the mating surfaces with alcohol? Is there a reason the strips are acting up?

Comment: the vibration of the move may have caused the zebra strip to vibrate and pull away from its contacts briefly and dirt dropped into the space between the zebra strip and the contact

Comment: Could you post photo's of what you are talking about. Certain types of damage are fixable, and some are not.

Comment: I've cleaned zebra strips with alcohol. Not sure if it's the best method, but I haven't had any problems.